# AS3: Error while accessing a function of an externally loaded swf file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I get the following error:

**Error #1069: Property externalFun not found on LoadedFile and there is no default value.**

My main project file:

```
        questionLoader = new Loader();
        var questionRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(xmlName);
        questionLoader.load(questionRequest);
        questionLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoaded);

 public function swfLoaded(e:Event) {

        var target: MovieClip = e.currentTarget.content;
        trace(target);

        addChild(target);
        target.externalFun();
    }
```

Loaded swf:

```
   public function LoadedFile() {
        // constructor code

        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);

    }

    public function externalFun():void {

    trace("IT WORKS");

    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Listen to **Event.INIT** rather than **Event.COMPLETE**. **Event.COMPLETE** happens immediately after all bytes are loaded and does not indicate that loaded content is actually available already. If you care to put one **trace** before calling **externalFun** and the other into the **LoadedFile** constructor, the latter one will fire later than the former. However, **Event.INIT** occurs after the loaded content is initialized thus the problem *probably* will go away. If no, proceed with **trace** diagnostics described above and probably wait 1 frame after **Event.INIT** fires before calling the function you want.